# Cyclic monotonicity of sub-differential domain and convex property

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

I am looking for hints/proof's overview/reference about this proposition :

> Let $S\subset \mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d$.
>   There exist a convex function $\phi$ such that $S\subset \partial\phi$ if and only if $S$ is cyclically monotone.

Here $\partial\phi$ denotes the sub-differential of $\phi$.

Comment: ps : I am a french computer science student and I didn't have much time to delve deeper that's why I asked this question.

Comment: Look into H. Brezis; Opérateurs maximaux monotones et semi-groupes de contractions dans les espaces de Hilbert, North-Holland (1973) for a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Theorem 24.8 in *[Convex Analysis](http://books.google.com/books?id=1TiOka9bx3sC)* by Rockafellar.  The necessity is easy, because for every $x_1,\dots,x_m$ and every choice of $y_k\in \partial \phi(x_k)$ we have 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m \langle x_{k+1}-x_k, y_k \rangle  \le \sum_{k=1}^m (f(x_{k+1})-f(x_k)) =0  
$$
where  $x_{m+1}=x_1$.

The sufficiency takes an effort, but the idea is to fix $(x_1,y_1)$ in the graph of $S$ and define 
$$
\phi(x) = \sup \sum_{k=1}^m \langle x_{k+1}-x_k, y_k \rangle 
$$
where this time $x_{k+1}=x$. The supremum is taken over all $m$ and all selections of pairs $(x_k,y_k)\in S$. Then one checks that $\phi$ is convex and satisfies $S\subset \partial \phi$.